# How to name an asset in ethereum? And associating quantity for that asset?

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to create an asset say **'cotton'** with quantity as **100 tonnes**.
I want to use this asset for *Trade and Finance*. Please suggest how to create this asset with the given quantity.

Comment: Its a specific question and i have given my use case as well. Please suggest if i need to re-frame it in any other way.